# Excel - Have tab show filtered results from another tab for a specific named person

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get Excel to have a second tab(sheet) display filtered results from tab1(sheet1) based on the column value matching a string 'John Smith' -- is that possible?

What I've tried:  `='Core_Team'!$I="John Smith"`

So in this case, tab1 is named 'Core_Team' and I tried this formula in tab2, A1 where I'm trying to have the worksheet display all rows where the cell values of column 'I' from tab1 has the value, 'John Smith'.

Is this possible in forumula or do I need to go to VBA?

TIA!

Edit 1:  Example information

Tab1:

```
Employed,Rank,Location,Days,Hours,Minutes,Seconds,Miliseconds,Employee
Y,1,CA,30,21,8,30,1024,John Smith
Y,3,WA,30,21,8,30,1024,Nancy Johnson
Y,1,CA,30,21,8,30,1024,John Smith
Y,2,TX,30,21,8,30,1024,Hari Kolli
Y,2,TX,30,21,8,30,1024,Hari Kolli
Y,1,CA,30,21,8,30,1024,John Smith
```

Tab2:

```
[Display in this sheet all rows where the 'I' column (employee) from Sheet1 matches 'John Smith']
```

Comment: If you have `FILTER()` it is possible.  That is available in office 365.  There are other formula that can do it, also in older versions.  Can you give use enough info to reproduce what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

If one has Office 365 with FILTER():

```
=FILTER(A:I,I:I="John Smith")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect thanks Scott -- and here's the applied filter using alternately referenced sheets that I applied using your example:  =FILTER(Core_Team!A:M,Core_Team!I:I="John Smith")

Answer (score 1):

### Name in cell

Let's say you have `John Smith` in `K1` on `Core_Team`, you could then use this formula in another tab to pull the data for that person from the `Core Teams` tab.

```
 =FILTER(Core_Team!A:I, (Core_Team!I:I=Core_Team!K1)+(ROW(Core_Team!I:I)=1))
```

### Name hard-coded

If you don't want to use a cell for the name you can hard-code it in the formula like this.

```
    =FILTER(Core_Team!A:I, (Core_Team!I:I="John Smith")+(ROW(Core_Team!I:I)=1))
```

Note, both formulas also pull over the header row, which might not be required -  if it isn't remove `+(ROW(Core_Team!I:I)=1)` from the formula.

Comment: I like the header information but you example is missing the always-pull-string-value-from-tab1-columnI-that-matches-string-John Smith

Comment: Not sure I follow, are you dealing with 3 different sheets? One with the data, `Core_Team` and 2 others, one for the name and one for the pulled data.

Comment: No only two sheets.  What I was trying to say is that when I ran this formula in my sheet2, it only pulled over the header information from Sheet1, but no data from Sheet1, Column 'I' that matched 'John Smith'.

Comment: In the formula I posted you would need to put `John Smith`, or whatever name you want, into `K1` on `Core_Team` for it to work. If you want to hard-code the name in the formula I'll edit the answer to show that.

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for -- tab 1 will constantly be added to so the formula I was after should update tab 2 to show wherever entries for "John Smith" in Tab 1's K column appear and not hard-coded to specific cells.  Scott's answer does that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Excel advanced Filters, seeing your requirement, I hope this must be helpful.
Check this link: https://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter01.html

Crisp Of link:

1. go to cell other than your table write column name and string you want to match
2. Go to Sheet2 define all columns there also.
3. Select a cell in an unused part of the sheet .
4. On the Excel Ribbon's Data tab, click Advanced.
5. Choose Copy to another location.
6. Click in the List Range box.
7. Select Sheet1, and select the database.
   Click in the Criteria range box.
8. Select the criteria range i.e first point.
9. Click in the Copy to box.
10. Select the cell on Sheet2 in which you want the results to start, or select the headings that you have typed on Sheet2.
11. (optional) Check the box for Unique Values Only.

Thank You!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I have updated the Answer.